# How to reference a React class from generic javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flux

I have this index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample App</title>
  <link href="./src/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="./src/css/bootstrap.dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id='root'>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/js/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:26665/signalr/hubs"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundle.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var myHub = $.connection.signalRTwitchBotParserHub;

        myHub.client.OnNewMessage = function (data) {
              // Call AppActions.dispatchMessage(message);
        };

        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:26665/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.start()
   });
  </script>
</body>
```

How can I call a React-created class from there? I would like to replace the `// Call AppActions.dispatchMessage(message);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following. What that does is create an instance of `YourReactClass` that renders itself as a child of your div with the id of `root`. It also passes the `message` as a property into the react instance so that it can make use of that data. Note that I added `key="rootclass"` to ensure that every time this code is called, React continues to reuse the DOM nodes created by the react class instead of removing the old nodes and adding new ones.

```
React.render((<YourReactClass key="rootclass" message={message} />), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include React onto the page by adding

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
```

See the [full list of downloads](http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html) for other includable options (such as the JSX Transformer).